# Criação e alteração de usuários e permissões

Tags: mongodb

Eu tenho executado o mongod com a configuração padrão, ou seja, não tenho definido nem o *path*, nem a porta, e nem ativado o *access control*.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongod
```

Tentando "coisas mais avançadas", eu quis criar o usuário **admin** e usar esse para criar outros usuários (como a documentação indica). Mas estou tendo muita dificuldade ainda, muitos comandos retornam com o seguinte (ou algo próximo):

```
not authorized on admin to execute command
```

O usuário *admin* foi criado da seguinte maneira:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Mas ele parece só ter autorização para criar outros usuários.

> Eu gostaria de saber:
>
> Como criar um usuário e dar acessos básicos a uma *database*
>
> Como atualizar as permissões de um usuário
>
> Como apagar um usuário

Do jeito mais simples e *straightforward* possível! :)

O intuito é passar a executar o mongodb com *access control*:

```
mongod --auth
```

Comment: no roles, tente: `roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]`

Answer (score 1):

**Sobre o parâmetro writeConcern**: Antes de falar dos comandos vou deixar aqui uma descrição do objeto *writeConcern*, que é parâmetro opcional de todos os comandos abaixo. Ele indica como o banco vai se comportar/confirmar durante a execução do comando. São três atributos possíveis dentro dele:

- **w** - Quantas instâncias você quer que confirmem a operação. A opção *majority* pede que a maioria dos nodos votantes confirme a operação. Mais informações [aqui](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#w-option).
- **j** - Pede confirmação que os nodos tenham escrito os dados no *journal*. Mais informações [aqui](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#j-option).
- **wtimeout** - Especifica um limite, em milisegundos, para esperar pela confirmação. Mais informações [aqui](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#wtimeout).

**Criar usuário e dar acessos básicos a um banco:** Considerando permissões básicas como habilidade de escrever e ler, a criação do usuário *joao* no banco *teste* ficaria assim:

```
use teste
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "joao",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "teste" } ]
  } 
  ,
  {
    w: "majority"
   ,wtimeout: 5000
  }
)
```

Você pode criar o usuário em qualquer banco, isso não limita que ele tenha permissões somente nesse banco. Você pode por exemplo criar dois usuários com o mesmo nome em bancos diferentes, com permissões diferentes. Na hora de acessar ele deve decidir contra qual banco ele está autenticando.

**Atualizar permissões:** Existem dois comandos para modificar permissões:

- Adicionar a permissão de administração de usuários no usuário de testes *joao* que criei antes: `db.grantRolesToUser( "joao", [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ], {w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000})`
- Remover a permissão de administração de usuários do *joao*: `db.revokeRolesFromUser( "joao", [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ], {w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000})`.

Existem papéis pré definidos, que estão listados [aqui](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#built-in-roles).

**Apagar um usuário:** você pode usar o comando `db.dropUser(usuario, writeConcern)`. O primeiro parâmetro é o login do usuário, o segundo é o objeto que expliquei no início da resposta. Abaixo um exemplo para excluir o usuário *joao* do banco *teste*:

```
use teste
db.dropUser("joao", {w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000})
```